# Renaming `database.php.default` to `database.php`in `\app\Config\` in CAKEPHP gives Error

Tags: php, cakephp, database-connection, cakephp-2.1

Renaming `database.php.default` to `database.php`in `\app\Config\` in CAKEPHP gives Error

I have installed a fresh copy of CAKEPHP 2.1.3 on XAMPP with Windows 7 and i have got an error

```
Warning (2): include_once(D:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\example\app\Config\database.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory [CORE\Cake\Model\ConnectionManager.php, line 68]


Warning (2): include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'D:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\example\app\Config\database.php' for inclusion (include_path='D:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\example\lib;.;D:\xampp\php\PEAR') [CORE\Cake\Model\ConnectionManager.php, line 68]
```

When i look into for `database.php` file in `\app\config\` its not present

Instead, i found `database.php.default` in `\app\Config\` and `\lib\Cake\Console\Templates\skel\Config`

And when i rename the `database.php.default` to `database.php`, it still gives me an error.
How do i need to connect to database and next procedure to go ahead.

Comment: make sure you renamed the one in `\app\Config` and not `\lib\Cake...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move config file from `\lib\Cake\Console\Templates\skel\Config` to `D:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\example\app\Config\`

Or create new one with contents:

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'databas name',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );

}
```